# Emulate serial ports in absence of serial ports

Tags: qt4, serial-port

I'm very new to serial port/windows programming... and need to communicate with a microcontroller device via serial ports. Since I've some working knowledge of Qt, I've decided to write the GUI application using `Qt`, `QSerialDevice` etc.

I've a laptop with no serial device. **Now I don't understand how I'll be experimenting on serial ports even if I do not have them!** (Don't laugh at my ignorance) -  Please provide me some insight how I can test the behaviors/test my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Franson makes [a whole set of serial port tools](http://franson.com/virtual-serial-port/), including loopback ports.

If you just need a loopback, there is a free driver available:  http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

If you want to interface with an actual device, you'll need to pick up a USB-to-serial converter.  They're only $2 or so.

Comment: +1 for the com0com ... it's free :) I also found another one.. http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html it's free too.